# Через сколько времени без 301 ридиректа, сменится статья если я изменил к ней путь, в гугле?

Tags: seo, google-search

Хотелось бы узнать когда в гугле поменяется статья если я поменял к ней путь с http://mysite.com/my_article на http://mysite.com/my-article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Нужно иметь sitemap
2. Нужно иметь аккаунт в [Инструментарии для веб мастеров Google](https://google.com/webmasters/tools/home)
3. Чтобы Google сразу просканировал sitemap, нужно в панели управления запустить инструмент “Посмотреть как Googlebot”.
   p.s. я думаю после этого он поменяет путь на статью

Comment: Не поменяет - он начнет видеть, что по новому адресу такой же контент, и может просто заблокировать 2 страницы. (404 поисковик тоже очень не любит

Comment: но если старой страницы больше не существует, после того как он прочел сайтмап, то он ее индексировать больше не будет, то не должен заблокировать, а там пойди знай как на самом деле, нужно пробовать

Comment: Для каждой страницы есть свое время переиндексации,в зависимотси от сайта. В среднем - 2 недели для небольших сайтов. Вот и будет робот думать, что у него 2 одинаковые страницы. Веса у новой не будет - место старой точно не скоро займет (если займет) и будет выдавать 404, что очень плохо, т.к. страница раньше была, а теперь нету, и куда она ушла - неизвестно, т.к. единственный указатель переезда - редирект.

Comment: тогда может имеет смысл использовать редирект дублей через .htaccess

Comment: имеет смысл, о чем я написал в своем ответе. Это одно из железных правил - переехала страница - 301/302 в зависимости от ситуации

Comment: через вебмастер тулс , попросил индиксацию статей, статьи поменялись меньше чем за 24 часа в гугле, мне очень помог ваш ответ. спасибо